# Problem with discrete random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 15 cakes on table, 9 with chocolate and 6 with strawberry. Marry randomly picks 5 cakes and eats them. Whats the probability that she ate between 5 and 7 chocolate cakes?

I assumed this is hipergeometric distribution because she doesnt return the cakes so each time she pickes a cake there are less of them. Anyway i used the formula for finding the probability that she picked 5 cakes and just calculated that. I ignored the 6 and 7 since the probability is 0 because she cant pick more than 5 cakes. I got 0.958 but the solution says 0.911.

I dont know if my solution is wrong or the solution in the book. Can someone check my answer please? Thanks.

Comment: Please re-read your problem statement. As it stands, the answer is $1$ (or $0$, depending on the meaning of between).

Comment: @J.G. oh the probability that she ate between 5 and 7 chocolate cakes. Ill edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given the total number of cupcakes $N=15$

Chocolate cupcakes $C=9$

Strawberry cupcakes $S=6$

Randomly chosen cupcakes $n=5$

Let $X_c$ be the number of chocolate cupcakes selected by the child and $Y$ be the number of chocolate cupcakes remaining on the plate after selection. Then the random variable $X_c$ has a hypergeometric distribution with $N=15,S=6,n=4$ and the probability mass function of this random variable will be $P(X_x=x)=\dfrac{\dbinom9x\times\dbinom{15-9}{5-x}}{\dbinom{15}{5}}$ for max $\{0,5+9-15\}\le x\le$ min$\{5,9\}$ which is $P(X_c=x)=\dfrac{\dbinom9x\times\dbinom{6}{5-x}}{\dbinom{15}{5}}$ for $0\le x\le5$

So, the probability that she ate between 5 and 7 chocolate cakes is $$P(5\le X\le7)=P(X=5)+P(X=6)+P(X=7)$$
$$P(X_c=9-5)+P(X_c=9-6)+P(X_c=9-7)=P(X_c=4)+P(X_c=3)+P(X_c=2)$$
$$=\dfrac{\dbinom94\cdot\dbinom61}{\dbinom{15}{5}}+\dfrac{\dbinom93\cdot \dbinom62}{\dbinom{15}{5}}+\dfrac{\dbinom92\cdot\dbinom63}{\dbinom{15}{5}}$$
$$=\dfrac{126\cdot6}{3003}+\dfrac{84\cdot15}{3003}+\dfrac{36\cdot20}{3003}=\dfrac{912}{1001}\approx 0.911$$

Comment: Can you explain the second line? I dont get it. I mean it looks like you were finding probablities of chosing 4 choc 1 straw; 3 choc 2 straw; and 2 choc 3 straw cakes.

Comment: Let $X_c$ be the number of chocolate cupcakes selected by the child and $Y$ be the number of chocolate cupcakes remaining on the plate after selection. Then the random vaiable $X_c$ has a hypergeometric distribution with $N=15,S=6,n=4$ and the probability mass function of this random variable will be $P(X_x=x)=\dfrac{\dbinom9x\cdot\dbinom{15-9}{5-x}}{\dbinom{15}{5}}$ for max $\{0,5+9-15\}\le x\le $ min{5,9}

Comment: I dont understand the limits that you wrote and I dont get why x takes values from 4 to 2 instead of 5 to 7.

Comment: @Dangz1 See the edited the answer.

Comment: Okay the fact that its asking for probability of her eating more than she picked is confusing me and I just dont get it. I mean I get your answer but I dont get the reasoning behind it. Also why 9-5, 9-6 and 9-7.